# Counting the nonwhitespace in a String

Tags: java, count

How would I count the nonwhitespace in String in Java?

Only thing I can declare is the `int nonwhitespace = 0;` That is all I can think of.

Comment: Start by going through the `String` javadoc. How do you determine what is non whitespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code below should work.

```
int total = 0;

for(int i=0; i < str.length(); i++)
{

   if(!Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(i)))
     total++;
}

System.out.println("total non-whitespace characters are " + total);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
int nonwhitespace = text.replaceAll("\\w","").length();
```

Answer (score 0):

May be first replace all whitespaces and then count the length?

`str.replaceAll("\\s+","")` - to remove whitespaces..

`str.length()` -- to then count the number the nonwhite space chars